# To retrieve not null value

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement is

```
select *

from emp

where comm is not null;
```

How to find not null (or) null values without using null (or) not null keyword.

Comment: "without using null (or) not null keyword" --- what is the technical reason behind this requirement?

Comment: `select *
from emp
where comm <> '' ;`

Comment: @Vijaykumar Hadalgi: what if it's a number?

Comment: Is this a question from some quiz? Maybe they are looking for something like **select * from emp where comm = comm**

Comment: @Thomas Padron-McCarthy:No sir it is for task given in training ..This query You posted is perfectly works for finding not null value .. how to find the null values

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi, `comm <> ''` will always be "unknown".

Comment: This question has no value to anyone. Even if it's truly a problem posed in a training class, giving the answer will not benefit the trainee either, as the only possible reason for posing it is to make the trainee *think* about it for themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to avoid using `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`?  That's the simplest and most logical approach.

If you're really determined

```
WHERE nvl( comm, -99 ) = -99
```

will also give you all the rows where `comm` is `NULL` assuming that `comm` can never have a value of -99.

```
WHERE comm > -99
```

will give you all the rows where `comm` is `NOT NULL` assuming all non-NULL values of `comm` are greater than -99.

It would make no sense to actually write a query this way, however, when you can use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` and end up with a much more maintainable query.

Comment: Yes sir not null keyword is the best way ,but task given for me is without using not null or null keyword in query..I am new to oracle sir so i find difficult in that

Answer (score 1):

Well, this will only return rows where comm is not null, since null is not equal to anything, not even itself.

```
select * from emp where comm = comm
```

to do the reverse, I would say something like

```
select * from emp
except
select * from emp where comm = comm
```

Replace 'except' with 'minus' or whatever is the equivalent in your system.

Beware these, which won't work

```
select * from emp where not(comm = comm)
select * from emp where comm <> comm
```

null==null is "unknown", not "false", and not(unknown) is unknown again.  It's a thing.

Comment: select * from emp where comm <> comm        returns no rows selected sir

Comment: @viki: Yes, that's why Darren wrote that those two commands won't work.

Comment: @Thomas: yes sir I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

1) Null
   =====
select * from emp
where nvl(length(comm),0) = 0

2) Not Null
   =========

select * from emp
where nvl(length(comm),0) <> 0